# How do I remove old version numbers of an application? (SAS Enterprise Guide query of a dataset)

Tags: sas

I am a huge newbie, so please forgive my baby-level question:

I have a dataset. In this dataset, we are capturing information in an application. There is a Client ID, an application ID, and a application version.

I need to (1) delete old versions of any given application ID and (2) sum application $$ requests for the application.

So, I need a way to analyse a set (all rows with the same application ID) and then delete all rows in the set that do not have the highest # value for the application number.
Then, I need to get a new set (all rows with the same client ID) and then add up the columns of $$ asks.

Does this make sense? Assume we have 4 rows: client_ID, application_ID, version_num, grant_request

I am going through UDEMY's introductory course and reading a book I bought, but I'm a newb. I use SAS Enterprise Guide. Even a link to a youtube would be eappreciated.

Comment: I would recommend the free courses on the SAS training site instead of Udemy and the Little SAS Book.

Comment: Please post your data rather than describe it and include the input, output and your business logic and whatever code you've attempted. Makes it much easier to help you. This is an easy usage of the FIRST/LAST concepts in SAS with a sort. If you have multiple rows per Appliation ID/Version then it's a touch more complex but still doable. Sample data would really help.

Comment: Different clients might have different application versioning.  Do you want to remove the older versions per client, or globally across all clients.  If removing globally some clients may disappear (get removed).